# AJAX Option to Joomla

Tags: jquery, ajax, joomla, mootools

I am using Joomla 1.5 ,The Mainmenu has the 5 Submenu, Each click of Menu goes to Article that specified one ( I mean Instead of redirect to link it should On same page). Instead is it possible make  AJAX the all Articles.

If so how to do it any idea ? (JQuery or What ever the ajax methods welcome)

Comment: its difficult understanding what you are asking for?

Comment: I mean to say the Menu should not redirect the link another page; instead it should show the article in same page

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get your question right but can't you change the `Menu Item Type` to `Article Layout` to show your article?